# Finding value from a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding value in my webpage as hidden like this:

```
cell.append('<input type="hidden" class="isTestValue" value="' + bill.IsTestBill + '">');
```

Now I wrote to get this value:

```
function getIsTestId(billIndex) {
    var selectedRow = getSelectedRow(billIndex);
    var lastCol = jQuery(selectedRow).find('TD:last');
    return (lastCol.find('INPUT:hidden.isTestValue).val());
}
```

However, in my function when I am calling this getIsTestId:

```
 var testId= getIsTestId(billIndex);
```

In testId the value is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: How should I check my isTestValue in immediate window?

Comment: Check your browser's javascript console for syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a single quote in this line `return (lastCol.find('INPUT:hidden.isTestValue).val());`, try this.

```
return lastCol.find('input.isTestValue').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a minor typo, missing semicolon, in return statement, there might be other issues, but try this first...

```
function getIsTestId(billIndex) {
    var selectedRow = getSelectedRow(billIndex);
    var lastCol = jQuery(selectedRow).find('TD:last');
    return lastCol.find('INPUT:hidden.isTestValue').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed quotation in this line:

```
lastCol.find('INPUT:hidden.isTestValue');
```

And as another answerer pointed out, I think it's supposed to be:

```
lastCol.find('input.isTestValue').val();
```